# Create a batch file to load a webpage when the date and time are correct

Tags: datetime, batch-file, html

I am trying to get a webpage to load when the date and time are correct. The code I have come up with is:

```
@echo off
:repeat
set CurrentTime=%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%
set CurrentDate=%date:/=-%
echo.
echo %CurrentDate% %CurrentTime%
echo.
IF %CurrentTime% == Tue 08-04-2014 13.04 goto load
timeout /t 1 >nul
goto repeat
:load
start/MAX iexplore.exe"" "http://www.youtube.com.au"
timeout /t 6 >nul
```

It will work if I remove the CurrentDate and the date from the IF statement but it won't if I don't. I do need the date and time to work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF "%date% %Time%"=="Tue 08-04-2014 13.04" goto load
```

shoud work for you. You need to use the "quotes" to group the string as a single entity, otherwise `IF` has no way of telling whether the `==` is a part of the string to be compared or it's the comparison operator. (and that assumes that your date format is `Tue 08-04-2014` and time is `13.04`)

Answer (score 0):

Aditionally to the solution that Magoo has posted, note that `%DATE%` returns the current date using the *short date format* that is fully and endlessly customizable by the users. One user may configure its system to return `Tue 08/04/2014` and another user may choose `Apr8th14`. It's a complete nightmare for a BAT programmer. Even in the same computer. This is also true for the `~t` modifier when expanding a variable containing a filename.

There are several solutions, google a bit to find them. The easiest in my opinion is to use **WMIC**

```
 WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day,Hour,Minute,Month,Second,Year /Format:table
```

returns the date in a convenient way to directly parse with a `FOR` command.

```
 FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
    SET /A currentdate=%%F*10000+%%D*100+%%A
 )
 IF "%currentdate"=="20140408" goto load
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a scheduled task if that suits the reason for you wanting to load the page.